# Android: How to display custom keyboard in SearchView?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, searchview, android-keypad

How to show custom keyboard view in SearchView in Android application?

I have designed custom keyboard for indic unicode language which works with EditText view fine.

I want to attach keyboard with SearchView, please suggest available option to hide default keyboard and show custom keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been following [this tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm), there are some tweaks needed to be able to use the SearchView in an action bar instead of the EditText.

Methods changed are registerEditText and the onKey in the OnKeyBoardActionListener:

**registerEditText**, now registerSearchView

```
    public void registerSearchView(SearchView searchView, final MenuItem searchMenuItem){
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mHostActivity.getComponentName()));
    this.searchMenuItem = searchMenuItem;
    final IBinder searchToken = searchView.getWindowToken();
    searchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.d("Focus change", "hasFocus: " + hasFocus);

            if (hasFocus) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
            else
                hideCustomKeyboard();

        }
    });

    //The searchview clicked after the it is already in focus
    searchView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    //When the searc view is clicked before it is focused
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(onClickListener);

    searchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("Touch", event.getAction() + "");
            SearchView searchViewTemp = (SearchView) v;
            int inType = searchViewTemp.getInputType();         //backup the input type
            searchViewTemp.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);   //Disable standard keyboard
            searchViewTemp.onTouchEvent(event);
            searchViewTemp.setInputType(inType);
            return true;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            searchMenuItem.collapseActionView(); //collapsing the searchview after search
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    //Disable spell check
    searchView.setInputType(searchView.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("onClick", v.getLayerType()+"");
        showCustomKeyboard(v);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
};
```

**onKey**

```
@Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        Class currentClass = focusCurrent.getClass();
        Class searchClass = mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.action_line_search).getClass();
        SearchView.SearchAutoComplete sac = new SearchView.SearchAutoComplete(mHostActivity);
        Class searchAutoCompleteClass = sac.getClass();
        EditText editText = (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.edittext_search_lines);
        Class editTextClass = editText.getClass();

        if( focusCurrent.getClass() == SearchView.SearchAutoComplete.class) {

            SearchAutoComplete searchView = (SearchAutoComplete) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = searchView.getText();
            int start = searchView.getSelectionStart();
            if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE) {
                Log.d("onKey", "Search Clicked");
                mHostActivity.sendQuery(editable);
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
                Log.d("onKey", "Deleting input");
                if (editable != null && start > 0)
                    editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } else {
                Log.d("onKey", "Letter or number clicked");
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when you want to register you SearchView, you use the new registerSearchView in you activity or fragment.

But a new problem arises: The default soft keyboard appears on top of the custom keyboard. If you figure out how to remove it, please tell me! :D